# Find rows with 2 or more matching properties in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

This one is stumping me, I will just go ahead and explain via SQL. Here is the data structure:

**Property**

```
PropertyId     Name         
1              Property one
2              Property two
```

**Property Features**

```
PropertyFeatureId     FeatureId     PropertyId
1                     1             1
2                     2             1
3                     1             2
```

**Feature**

```
FeatureId     Name
1             Hot tub
2             Wifi
```

How would I go about finding all properties that have a hot tub AND wifi? So in the example above I would want propery 1, but not 2.

One way I suppose is inner-joining and filtering by the ones we want, but I want to generalize this so I can find all properties with feature A, B, C and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is to count the number of instances of propertyName and that it is equal to the number of values supplied in the `WHERE` clause condition.

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    Property a
        INNER JOIN [Property Features] b
            ON a.PropertyID = b.PropertyId
        INNER JOIN Feature c
            ON b.FeatureID = c.FeatureID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Hot tub','Wifi')
GROUP BY a.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.Name) = 2
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b4b6/1)

Comment: AHHHH. I see what you did there :)